# How do i insert a date time picker date into sql server from vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

[Visual Studio error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRrpW.png)

```
con.Open()
cmd.CommandText = "insert into TBL_STUDENT values (@lrn,@fn,@mn,@ln,@ext,@add,@gen,@cont,@date,@place,@citi,@reli,@father,@fatherscont,@mother,@motherscont,@guardian,@guardianscont,@lastschool,@grade)

With cmd.Parameters
    .Clear()
    .AddWithValue("lrn", TXT_LRN.Text)
    .AddWithValue("fn", TXT_FN.Text)
    .AddWithValue("mn", TXT_MN.Text)
    .AddWithValue("ln", TXT_LN.Text)
    .AddWithValue("ext", TXT_EXT.Text)
    .AddWithValue("add", TXT_ADDRESS.Text)
    .AddWithValue("gen", TXT_GENDER.Text)
    .AddWithValue("cont", TXT_CONTACT.Text)
```

Comment: You need to set the datetime parameter value to the picker `Value` property. Add your VB code to your question. The error message in the image obfuscated the code in the screenshot.

Comment: Please avoid posting images of your code. My guess is that it's the use of `AddWithValue` inferring the wrong data type, but it's only a guess since the error message hides the code.

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "insert into TBL_STUDENT values (@lrn,@fn,@mn,@ln,@ext,@add,@gen,@cont,@place,@citi,@reli,@father,@fatherscont,@mother,@motherscont,@guardian,@guardianscont,@lastschool,@grade)"
        With cmd.Parameters

Comment: With cmd.Parameters
            .Clear()
            .AddWithValue("lrn", TXT_LRN.Text)
            .AddWithValue("fn", TXT_FN.Text)
            .AddWithValue("mn", TXT_MN.Text)
            .AddWithValue("ln", TXT_LN.Text)
            .AddWithValue("ext", TXT_EXT.Text)
            .AddWithValue("add", TXT_ADDRESS.Text)
            .AddWithValue("gen", TXT_GENDER.Text)
            .AddWithValue("cont", TXT_CONTACT.Text)

Comment: which field meant to store the date/time value? I can see all are `.Text`

Comment: @JoeBryBasil There are reasons why there are articles titled [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) and [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html). Also, the `@` seems to be missing from the parameter names.

Answer (score -2):

If you send dates from `VB.NET`, you can do a conversion to your `DATE` variables to canonical date format from `VB.NET` when you are building your query (in `VB.NET`) to avoid problems related to language configuration of the database. Remember when you are building your query to concatenate your variables to send your values to your procedure:

```
datevariablename.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

It will send your date to your stored procedure in that format

Hope it works

Comment: Converting a date to a string to pass it to a database is always a bad idea. Maybe not *always*, just 99.95% of the time.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Why it is a bad idea? Can you elaborate?

Comment: There are some reasons in [Why not return dates as a string from the database?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331653/why-not-return-dates-as-a-string-from-the-database)